# "OHHTTPStubs/OHHTTPStubs.h" file not found

Tags: ios, xcode6, ohhttpstubs

I have added lib `OHHTTPStubs` manually but it's showing error "`OHHTTPStubs/OHHTTPStubs.h`" file not found.
Appreciate for help.

Answer (score 0):

Is your project swift based? If so, Bridging header is the legit way of doing it.

Comment: To make this a useful answer, please explain the process for creating a bridging header and how that will solve the problem.